# How to store multiple text messages in array using plist

Tags: iphone

How do I store multiple text messages and phone numbers in an array using plist?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to be more precise on what you want. Do you want to store strings contained in an array in a plist, or what?
If that's what you want, you may use NSDictionary's `+(id)dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path` and then convert your dictionary into array